# Pegar objeto ao clicar em uma commandLink no DataTable

Tags: jsf, primefaces, java-ee

Estou tentando pegar um objeto ao clicar em um commandLink que fica em cada coluna da DataTable, porém sempre da erro de nullPointerException. Alguem pode ajudar?

Estou fazendo dessa forma:

```
<p:commandLink id="ajax"  ajax="false" process="@this"
    actionListener="#{controleAuditoriaBean.prepDownload}" value="#{controleAuditoria.caminhoArquivo}">
            <f:setPropertyActionListener
                target="#{controleAuditoriaBean.solicitacoesBD}"
                            value="#{controleAuditoria}" />                         
                    <p:fileDownload value="#{controleAuditoriaBean.download}" />    
</p:commandLink>
```

Método:

```
public void prepDownload() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Caminho "+solicitacoesBD.getCaminhoArquivo());
        File file = new File(solicitacoesBD.getCaminhoArquivo());

        InputStream input = new FileInputStream(file);
        ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
        setDownload(new DefaultStreamedContent(input, externalContext.getMimeType(file.getName()), file.getName()));
        System.out.println("PREP = " + download.getName());
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Techies, seu problema está em utilizar o `actionListener` enquanto que o correto seria apenas `action`.

O problema do `actionListener` é que ele executa antes do `action`.

Seu código ficaria:

```
<p:commandLink id="ajax"  ajax="false" process="@this"
    action="#{controleAuditoriaBean.prepDownload}" value="#{controleAuditoria.caminhoArquivo}">
            <f:setPropertyActionListener
                target="#{controleAuditoriaBean.solicitacoesBD}"
                            value="#{controleAuditoria}" />                         
                    <p:fileDownload value="#{controleAuditoriaBean.download}" />    
</p:commandLink>
```

Comment: Funcionou, porém tenho que clicar 2x no link pra começar o download do arquivo. Seu clico 1x ele pega o objeto certinho mas o download não inicia.

Comment: @Techies Você pode voltar pra `actionListener` e tenta passar o valor por parâmetro ao invés de `f:setPropertyActionListener`, experimenta!

Comment: Pra passar por parâmetro não preciso usar o `f:setPropertyActionListener`?

Comment: Depende da versão do seu jsf, qual é? :)

Comment: Creio que seja a 2.2

Comment: Pode sim, faz um `actionListener="#{controleAuditoriaBean.prepDownload(controleAuditoria)}" `

Comment: Voltei para o `actionListener`, você só precisa alterar seu método `prepDownload` para receber esse tipo de parâmetro

Comment: pra receber esse parametro no meu método uso o requestContext?

Comment: ou é só colocar o objeto no método pra receber esse parâmetro? por exemplo `prepDownload(Auditoria a)`

Comment: @Techies só colocar o objeto no método, igual seu último exemplo

Comment: Mais uma vez muito obrigado Maicon. Você tem me ajudado bastante.